# Получить строку по номеру

Tags: php

Вот к примеру спарсил я плейлист и мне нужны в нем первые 3 строки, как мне их получить?
Учитывая то, что длина строк всегда разная.

Comment: Пример исходной строки не помешало бы опубликовать.

Comment: Плейлист на диске? Тогда [file()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно из строковой переменной $text - тогда примерно так:

```
$text = preg_replace('/^\s+/','',$text);   
$array  = explode("\n",$text,4);
 /* $array - массив, в котором первые три єлемента - три строки, 
 а четвёртый - остаток строки */
```

Comment: так в том то и дело я знаю как из файла мне не нужно из файла мне надо из перменной которая получилась из курла

Comment: Тогда примерно так: $array  = explode("\n",$text);

Comment: Исправил ответ - дал пример кода